# Is this a good solution for showing a SnackBar in case of an error with Flutter and MobX?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx, snackbar

Yesterday I spent over ten hours trying to learn a bit of [MobX](https://mobx.pub/) and applying a simple `SnackBar` if there is an error coming from the API. My question is if the solution I found can be considered good and appropriate or there is a better one to be implemented.

```dart
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _controller = Modular.get<LoginController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Observer(
        builder: (context) {
          if (_controller.token?.error != null) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text(_controller.token?.error),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ));
            });
          }

          return Center(
            child: PrimaryButton(
              onPressed: () => _controller.authenticate(),
              text: 'Enviar',
              icon: Icons.send,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In case you're curious about it, I'm using [`flutter_modular`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular), hence the `Modular.get<>()`

Comment: Isn't that more of an UX question?

Comment: @Rena, no because what I meant is to ask if the way I did that, in code, is good or should be done differently, you understand? Not for the end user but for me as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach, that is as long as you make sure your snackbar **does NOT** cover the content of the page, as you know errors from API's could be complex and well documented, therefore you may come across a situation where the snackbar would cover your content.
I usually would use `showDialog` instead, as errors should not usually accur. when they do I would push a popup displaying and explaining the situation using the error details.

This is my customized version of popups:

```
class ButtonsAndAction extends FlatButton{
  ///Providing a func is "optional", just pass null if you want the defualt action to pop the navigator.
  ButtonsAndAction(BuildContext context, String text, Function func ) : super(child: new Text(text, textDirection: Helper.textDirection(),style: TextStyle(color: ConstantValues.mainBackgroundColor)
  ,), onPressed: func == null ? () {Navigator.of(context).pop();} : func);
}

class Helper{
  static TextDirection textDirection() => AppConfig.rtl ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr;

  /// Used to push alerts of texts with a set of actions(buttons and actions) if wanted
  static Future pushDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String body, {List<ButtonsAndAction> actions, bool dismissable = true}) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => dismissable,
        child:
        new AlertDialog(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(ConstantValues.roundRadius)),
          side: BorderSide(color: ConstantValues.mainBackgroundColor, width: ConstantValues.roundBorderWidthForPopup)),
          title: new Container(child: new Text(title, textDirection: textDirection(), style: TextStyle(color: ConstantValues.mainBackgroundColor),), width: double.infinity,),
          content: new Container(child: SingleChildScrollView(child:
            new Text(body, textDirection: textDirection(), style: TextStyle(color: ConstantValues.mainBackgroundColor))), 
            width: double.infinity),
          actions: actions
        ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by `SnackBar` not covering the content of the page? Like while it's showing not prevent user from doing something else? Is it even possible to happen? I didn't know. Also, the main purpose of my question was to know if that's alright to be done like that, because I didn't quite understand `WidgetsBinding`.

Comment: Oh I actually didn't use `WidgetBinding` yet but I think you'll do it better with my solution.
Any how, when you put a very long text into a snackbar it could potentionally cover content if it is not inside a scrollable widget.